# Infinite looping route in AuthGuard

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the routes when I use AuthGuard if I try to redirect the user to another page and he is not authorized or is logged into the system, he must redirect to the page he was on

How do I solve the infinite looping problem so that the system behaves the right way with only 1 redirect without looping

app.module.ts

```
 imports     : [
        AuthModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),
]
```

My file app.routing.ts

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from 'app/core/auth/guards/auth.guard';
import { NoAuthGuard } from 'app/core/auth/guards/noAuth.guard';
import { LayoutComponent } from 'app/layout/layout.component';
import { InitialDataResolver } from 'app/app.resolvers';

export const appRoutes: Route[] = [

    {path: '', pathMatch : 'full', redirectTo: 'user-login'},

    // roters system
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {path: 'sign-in', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-in/sign-in.module').then(m => m.SignInModule)},
            {path: 'sign-up', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/auth/sign-up/sign-up.module').then(m => m.ignUpModule)},
        ]
    },

    // routes system user
    {
        path       : '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children   : [
            {path: 'user', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)},
        ]
    },

    {
        path       : '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children   : [
            {path: 'page-1', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/page-1/page1.module').then(m => m.Page1Module)},
        ]
    },

   {
        path       : '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children   : [
            {path: 'page-2', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/page-2/page2.module').then(m => m.Page2Module)},
        ]
    },

    {
        path       : '',
        children   : [
            {path: 'page-3', loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/page-3/payment-plan.module').then(m => m.Page3Module)},
        ]
    },

    {
        path       : '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
        children   : [
            {path: 'page-4, loadChildren: () => import('app/modules/page-4/page4.module').then(m => m.Page4Module)},
        ]
    },

];
```

My page-1.routing

```
export const page1Routes: Route[] = [
    {
        path     : '',
        component: Page1Component
    }
];
```

My page-1.module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(logisticRegisterRoutes),
    ],
    exports: [
        
    ]
})
export class Page1Module
{
}
```

All modules follow the same pattern

AuthGuard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad, Route, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlSegment, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from 'app/core/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {

    constructor(
        private _authService: AuthService,
        private _router: Router
    ) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const redirectUrl = state.url === '/sign-out' ? '/' : state.url;
        return this._check(redirectUrl);
    }

    canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        let redirect;

      //Looping infinit
        if(this._authService.token !== null) {
           
            var pageUser = this._authService.page;

            if(redirect === '1') {
                pageRedired = '/page-1';
            }

            if(redirect === "2") {
                pageRedired = "/page-2";
            }
    
            if(redirect === "3") {
                pageRedired = "/page-3";
            }
    
        }

        if(state.url !== pageRedired && this._authService.token) {
            this._router.navigate([state.url]);

            return true;
        } else {
            const redirectUrl = state.url === '/sign-out' ? '/' : state.url;
            return this._check(redirectUrl);
        }
    }

    canLoad(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this._check('/');
    }

   private _check(redirectURL: string): Observable<boolean> {
           return this._authService.check()
            .pipe(
                switchMap((authenticated) => {

                    if (!authenticated) {
                        // Redirect to the sign-in page
                        this._router.navigate(['login'], { queryParams: { redirectURL } });

                        return of(false);
                    }
                 return of(true);
                })

            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `canActivateChild` you initialize `let redirect`, but you never read the GET-Param value, therefore it stays undefined.
Afterwards you assaign `pageRedired` only if `redirect` is 1 2 or 3, but its undefined.
Therefore the if-case `if(state.url !== pageRedired && this._authService.token) {` is always true and you always execute `this._router.navigate([state.url]);` that is just routing to your current url.